# DOM manipulation for Angular 2

Tags: dom, angular, virtual-dom

I have a "simple" question about Angular 2 internal DOM manipulation.  Is Angular 2 using Virtual DOM, Incremental DOM or  what.  I have been looking all over the internet to understand what Angular 2 uses for DOM manipulation internally but I can't seem to find it.

I understand how they create components and how they allow us the developers to use the encapsulation strategy we would like.

I understand it uses zones to detect change and observables to apply change but did they come up with their own logic for internal DOM manipulation or are they manipulating on real DOM?

React has virtual dom, Ember uses glimmer, other frameworks use incremental dom. What does Angular 2 uses?

TIA.

Comment: You can manipulate the DOM with directives in Angular2 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Hey @tibbus thanks for the comment.  I am looking to understand how Angular 2 manipulates the DOM internally.    React uses virtual DOM.

Comment: have a look at [ http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html ]

Comment: Guys I have read a lot of articles and that is one of those.  Please understand, Pretch is talking about how components can use different strategies for encapsulation.  You can use shadow DOM or emulated.  That is not my question. my question is once Angular 2 detects change what algorithm does it use to know what component changed and how to "patch" the real dom with that change.  Totally different topics I believe.

Comment: @btinoco to understand change detection strategy this will be of help http://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever we create a component, Angular puts its template into a
>   `shadowRoot`, which is the Shadow DOM of that particular component.
>   Doing that, we get DOM tree and style encapsulation for free, right?
>   But what if we don’t have Shadow DOM in the browser? Does that mean we
>   can’t use Angular 2 in those environments? We can. In fact, Angular 2
>   doesn’t use native Shadow DOM by default, it uses an emulation. To be
>   technically correct, it also doesn’t create a `shadowRoot` for our
>   components in case no native Shadow DOM is used.

More: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html#understanding-shadow-dom

Comment: Thanks for the answer @manolis. See React uses the virtual dom to manipulate dom internally. It does a diff on the real dom vs virtual dom and patches the node that changed. Ember manipulates the dom with Glimmer.  Then we have the incremental dom to manipulate dom in other frameworks.  I want to know what does Angular 2 uses? Something like virtual dom, glimmer, incremental dom, raw dom or what?